# bent over barbell row biceps usage

Tags: biceps, barbell, barbell-rows

I was told that I mainly use biceps to perform bent over barbell rows. However, I feel like I'm using my back. How can I find out to which extent are hands absorbing the load?

Comment: You should be feeling it in your lats, And, did you mean hands, or, biceps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out [EXRX's muscle activation list on the bent-over barbell row](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/BBBentOverRow.html), you'll note that the dozen or so muscles that make up the bicep and forearm are [syngerists and dynamic stabilizers](http://www.exrx.net/Kinesiology/Glossary.html#anchor1275394): not prime movers.

So while your arms are certainly involved in the lift, they are hardly the prime movers.

Even if you flip to an [underhand grip on your barbell bent-over row](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/BBUnderhandBentOverRow.html), which will put more emphasis on your lats, your back reminds the prime mover although I'd imagine there's more loading of the biceps.

And you can prove it yourself: you can normally barbell row much more than you can curl. Rowing 180lbs for 5RM is a typical weight to see, but I highly doubt that person will be curling 90lbs 5RM for the same reps.